# I can't refresh external javascript file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iis

I'm making some changes on my .js file and upload to server.
But I can't refresh .js file and I can't see my changes on my browser.

- I deleted all caches, cookies, temporary files, history on firefox
  and chrome.
- I disabled output caching on IIS.
- Even I delete my script file from folder, I can still see the file on
  the browser.

Do you know to how to refresh my file?

Comment: what kind of code you are doing ? show us code. we are happy to help.

Comment: have you tried to test in incog?

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya While that is sadly a relevant response for too many questions here, it is not even close to relevant for this.  What do you think the code will tell you in the context of this question?

Comment: If you've definitely cleared your cache and you're still getting the old file then the old file still exists on the server.  The best check is to just open the file by putting the url into your browser and doing a Ctrl+F5 (refresh without using the cache).  If you get the old file then that's what's there.  Check paths and filenames etc..  Obviously something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Archer I tried Ctrl + F5, Ctrl + Shift + R but I didn't get any solution. I know it save the file somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you open the file in your browser like I suggested, so you see the script in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One *hack* is to add a version like `?v=1` to js file.

```
<script src="script/something.js?v=1"></script>
```